# Fancybox isn't working, and no errors in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

Fancybox keeps opening these images in new windows.

There are no JS errors in console.

Here is my HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="//fpoimg.com/1200x800">
  <img src="//fpoimg.com/80x80" />
</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="//fpoimg.com/1200x800">
  <img src="//fpoimg.com/80x80" />
</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="//fpoimg.com/1200x800">
  <img src="//fpoimg.com/80x80" />
</a>
```

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

Is it something to do with them being remote images? I've never had this not work.

Racking my brain here.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure fancybox, isn't recognizing those as pictures since they're missing a proper image extension.

Inspecting the code and modifing it to this, makes the lightbox effect work. (Just used a random jquery image)

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/images/logo-jquery.png"><img src="//fpoimg.com/80x80"></a>
```

Comment: Definitely was the issue. Thank you!